# PHP OOP extending external class

Tags: php, oop

Im new to OOP in PHP. I just can't extend a class from an external file. They are both on the same folder.

**DB.php**

```
<?php

class DB {
   // some functions here
}
```

**Home.php**

```
<?php
require_once("DB.php");
class Home extends DB {
   // initialize db and some functions here
}
```

and I get an error:
**Fatal error**: Class 'DB' not found in \location\to\Home.php on line 3

Comment: You must `require` the file first.

Comment: You must `require` with absolute path. `require_once __DIR__ . '/DB.php';`

Comment: I update the question. It required the file just forgot to add to the question. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Thank you @zerkms, It worked. Please add your comment to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be an absolute path import

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/DB.php';
```

Why: because otherwise the relative import is evaluated relatively to your current working directory, which is basically can be anything during the runtime. So it's recommended to always require files with the absolute path.